# wanting to use sep="..." but I am not getting the result I want

Tags: python, function, cs50

I just started learning python. currently taking CS50p and want to understand why my code isn't working. I am trying to replace the spaces with (3) periods but I currently am not able to.

```
playback = input("Please write something that you'd like to see printed. Spaces will be replaced with 3 periods. ")  

print(playback, sep="...")
```

run --->
input: `this is cs50p` ; expected output: `this...is...cs50p`

When I run this:

```
playback = input("Please write something that you'd like to print out. Spaces will be replaced with 3 periods. ")

print("hello,", playback, sep="...")
```

I get `hello,...this is cs50p`

thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Have the course taught you about `split` and `join`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve this. The assumed input for all of the examples is `"test test test"`.

Firstly is with replace in string.

```
playback = input("Please write something that you'd like to print out. Spaces will be replaced with 3 periods. ")
print("hello,", playback.replace(" ", "..."), sep="...") 

Output:
hello,...test...test...test
```

Keep in mind that with this, the only time your `sep` comes into play is between your inclusion of `"hello,"` and `playback`, which would have the spaces replaced with `...`.

The second is with just split

```
playback = input("Please write something that you'd like to print out. Spaces will be replaced with 3 periods. ")

print("hello,", *playback.split(" ") , sep="...") 

Output:
hello,...test...test...test
```

The `*` in front of `playback.split()` "opens" the list returned by `split()` into multiple inputs, which is how the `sep` argument can work on it. However, I don't think that the use of `*` for opening iterables is something that your course will have covered this early on. Still, this is a good example of how the `sep` keyword in print works. It takes the all of the variables passed to it and adds the string passed to `sep` between each of them. Since `*playback.split()` opens up into multiple variables, `sep` can act upon the different strings

The third that I can think of is combining `split` and `join`

```
playback = input("Please write something that you'd like to print out. Spaces will be replaced with 3 periods. ")

playback = playback.split(" ")
playback = "...".join(playback)

print("hello,", playback, sep="...")

Output:
hello,...test...test...test
```

Again, the `sep` is only operating on `"hello,"` and `playback` as a string as playback will already have `...` inside it after splitting and joining.

The "expected output" you gave doesn't have the "hello" at the front, so you can just remove that from the print statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options:

```
playback = input("Please write something that you'd like to see printed. Spaces will be replaced with 3 periods. ")  

print(*playback.split(), sep="...")
print(playback.replace(' ', '...'))
```

The first option is probably better because the second will produce something you weren't expecting if the input contains multiple adjacent spaces

Answer (score 0):

Use `.replace()`:

```
print(playback.replace(" ","..."))
```

Answer (score -1):

sep of print only replace `,`

if you want to replace ' ' to '...', use string replace.

```
>>> b = input("some input")
some input>? this is cs50p
>>> b
'this is cs50p'
>>> b.replace(' ', '...')
'this...is...cs50p'
```

that is my code

Comment: Your answer is not related to question. You must first describe the reason of error then advise a solution